# Ubuntu Phone carrier disappeared

Tags: networking, ubuntu-touch, indicator, phone

I had my Ubuntu Phone configured with a carrier and working. After enabling / then disabling flight mode, the network never returned on my device. Seems to be related to [this Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-rtm/+source/ofono/+bug/1427439).

Comment: Thanks Fabby, I've got this issue triaged on LP already and just want to be sure that in case anyone runs into this issue in the wild there are some answers here.  Was just waiting 8 hours to post the solution since I am a newb on AskUbuntu.

Comment: **On-topic: Self-answer will be posted in 8 hours**

Answer (score 1):

After running into this problem the following steps got my phone back up and running  (Nexus 4, r214):

Open the terminal app on the phone and validate using password if configured

```
sudo stop urfkill
sudo rm /var/lib/urfkill/saved-states -rf
sudo reboot
```

The phone should come back up with the carrier re-enabled.